# WebGL: gl.copyTexImage2D race condition

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have inherited some WebGL code that shows signs of rendering artifacts caused by a race condition. The problem only occurs on certain hardware (on Nvidia dedicated, but not on Intel integrated graphics) and seems to be related to `gl.copyTexImage2D`.

The problematic code is structured as follows:

```
<draw things>             // render to frame buffer
gl.copyTexImage2D(...);   // copy frame buffer to texture
<draw more things>        // render to frame buffer
<bind texture to uniform> // start using texture
<draw overlays>           // render to frame buffer using data from the texture
```

Unfortunately the drawn overlays show artifacts that indicate incorrect data in the texture copied from the frame buffer. Again, this works perfectly fine on some hardware while it fails on different one.

I can fix the problem by adding a call to `gl.flush()` (or `gl.finish()` for what it is worth) after `gl.copyTexImage2D(...)`. While this solves my problem I am still wondering whether I am looking at an error in the WebGL implementation, or in my code.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As far as OpenGL is concerned (I'm not so firm on the details of WebGL) glCopyTexImage inserts a synchronization point, so there *should* not be a race condition there. However for performance reasons I'd not have a glCopyTexImage there anyway. Instead I'd prepare a second FBO and render target, do a glBlitFrameBuffer, switch to the second framebuffer and continue rendering there. This in general will give you better batching and also will very likely circumvent the problem you encountered.

Of course you're not using the texture as a source to render to a framebuffer it's been selected as target. Do you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would also expect a sync point, which is why I am confused. And no we're not reading & writing the same texture. Rendering happens to the default framebuffer only. 

Also thanks for the info about `glCopyTexImage` unfortunately that one hasn't made its way into WebGL yet.

Comment: @karhu: By "hasn't made it's way" I think you mean `gl.BlitFrameBuffer`(which is part of the WebGL 2.0 specs), not copyTexImage.